# Python update broke `apt-listchanges`, completely breaking apt & dpkg

Tags: debian, apt, python3, dpkg

- OS: Debian 11
- OG Python vertion: 3.9

I updated python to 3.10 and did `update-alternatives`, after which on running `pip` i got the error:

```sh
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -ne 10
```

After a bit of search i found a few solutions:

- `update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 1` [How to update-alternatives to Python 3 without breaking apt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46335142/12716520)
- `sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges{,.bak}}` from [All Debian package managers broken due to Python bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506646/)
- Confirming `DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::InfoFD "20";` line exists in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges`

I randomly did:

- `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 1`
- `update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 1`
- `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3.10 1`
- `update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/python3.10 1`

None of these fixed, so i decided to remove `python3.10` by removing the symlink and create symlink for python3.9, that didn't work. Now, i start getting the dpkg errors:

```sh
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I don't have the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges` anymore. Then i tried following methods:

```sh
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

`sudo apt install --reinstall python3` gives:

```sh
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.9.2-3_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.9.2-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.9.2-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I still have both my pythons 3.9 & 3.10, `apt update` doesn't overtly throw an error, `apt clean` doesn't return anything `upgrade` and `autoremove` returns:

```sh
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

A default suggestion has been to delete the offending package run `clean, autoremove & update`, since its python3 i don't want to delete it because so many packages and heck the OS depends on it and i am scared.

I highly appreciate this to be resolved without me having to re-install the OS.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same errors on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ after installing Python3.9.5 on the Stretch Raspbian system. Unfortunately, I should have updated the OS but now I have this. I really hope someone can help. It's really a terrible and annoying issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1142040)

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3{,-minimal,-apt}
sudo apt-get --reinstall install apt-listchanges
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).